# Convert float type to two short (high & low bytes)

Tags: c++, arrays, decode, encode, converters

I transfer data through serial port. on decoding side. I'm coding on transferring side follow the code from receiving side. I must encode data from float type (4 bytes) to high part and low part (short type) then transfer them.

I had the decoding code. What i must do on encoding side.

I tried convert `signed int si` from `float realSi` but it was wrong. I got value 0 of `signed int si`. below is decoding code.

```
unsigned short siH = msg->getDataWordArray()[1]
unsigned short siL = msg->getDataWordArray()[2]
signed int si = (siH << 16) | (siL & 0x0000ffff)
float realSi = (float)((float)si)*180/1073741824);
```

Comment: it seems that your transfer part has some problem, but not the type converting.Your question is what protocol is good?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to codec on my side for them to decode it to get the correct float value on their side.

Comment: The way you used is right, if you want to use it, you need check the error.The intrinsic theory is sending the binary data from server to client, and then decode at client.There are many opensource protocols.Maybe protobuffer is good for you

Comment: Thanks. I found the protocol for me. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a union, as shown in the example code below.  Keep in mind that this will only work if the computers on both sides of the serial connection are using the same floating-point format and the same endian-ness.  If they aren't, you'll need to add additional translation logic to handle those differences.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Foo
{
   unsigned short asShorts[2];
   float asFloat;
};

int main(int, char * *)
{
   // Convert a float into two shots
   Foo foo;
   foo.asFloat = 3.14159f;
   printf("For float value %f, the shorts are %u and %u\n", foo.asFloat, foo.asShorts[0], foo.asShorts[1]);

   // [... send the two asShorts values across the serial port here...]


   // Imagine this is the receiving-side code (after having received the two shorts)
   const unsigned short s1 = foo.asShorts[0];
   const unsigned short s2 = foo.asShorts[1];

   // Convert the two shorts back into a float
   Foo bar;
   bar.asShorts[0] = s1;
   bar.asShorts[1] = s2;
   printf("For shorts %u and %u, the float value is %f\n", s1, s2, bar.asFloat);


   return 0;
}
```

... btw, if you'd prefer to send/receive bytes rather than shorts, you could change the union to look like this instead:

```
union Foo
{
   unsigned char asBytes[4];
   float asFloat;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's well defined behaviour?

Comment: `Foo TX;
TX.f = 21.12*1073741824/180;
printf("Data to transfer:%5.5f ", TX.f*180/1073741824); //21.12
printf("\nThe shorts we got are %u and %u", TX.sh[0], TX.sh[1]);

// On receiver
Foo RX;
RX.sh[0] = TX.sh[0];
RX.sh[1] = TX.sh[1];
signed int si = (RX.sh[0] << 16) | (RX.sh[1] & 0x0000ffff);
float realSI = (float)(((float)si*180/1073741824)); //2^30
printf("\nResult on Reciever: %5.5f",realSI );//215.03871` 
It doesn't give a correct result